# How to insert multiple returns of the select statement?

Tags: sql-server, insert, query

I have 3 tables. `ClassList`, `Student` & `Faculty`. I'm trying to assign the faculty to a specific class, e.g. I'm assigning "John Doe" to the section "Section1" where this "Section1" exists in the `Student` table column.

Outcome:

#### Student table

```
 StudentID       Name    Section
    1            user1    Section1
    2            user2    Section1
    3            user3    Section2
```

#### Faculty table

```
 FacultyID       Name       Subject
    1            Faculty1   Subject ABC
    2            Faculty2   Subject DEF
```

#### ClassList table

```
  ClassListID        StudentID      FacultyID    ModifiedDate
```

My insert statement is like this:

```
INSERT INTO ClassList 
VALUES 
( 
    (
        SELECT Student.StudentID 
        FROM Student 
        WHERE Student.Section = 'Section1'
    ), 
    (
        SELECT Faculty.FacultyID 
        FROM Faculty 
        WHERE Faculty.FirstName = @FacultyName 
        OR Faculty.LastName = @FacultyName
    ), 
    GETDATE()
);
```

I know that the select statement in the `Student` table returning a lot so I'm wondering if there's a way to add all the return query of it into `ClassList` table?

Answer (score 2):

If all students returned by the first select need to be combined with all faculties returned by the second select, then you just need to cross-join the two subsets and select from the resulting set.  You can use either the classic comma join or the explicit `CROSS JOIN` syntax:

1. Comma join:

   ```
   INSERT INTO
     dbo.ClassList (StudentID, FacultyID, ModifiedDate)
   SELECT
     s.StudentID
   , f.FacultyID
   , GETDATE()
   FROM
     (
       SELECT Student.StudentID 
       FROM dbo.Student 
       WHERE Student.Section = 'Section1'
     ) AS s
   , (
       SELECT Faculty.FacultyID 
       FROM dbo.Faculty 
       WHERE Faculty.FirstName = @FacultyName 
       OR Faculty.LastName = @FacultyName
     ) AS f
   ;
   ```
2. `CROSS JOIN`:

   ```
   INSERT INTO
     dbo.ClassList (StudentID, FacultyID, ModifiedDate)
   SELECT
     s.StudentID
   , f.FacultyID
   , GETDATE()
   FROM
     (
       SELECT Student.StudentID 
       FROM dbo.Student 
       WHERE Student.Section = 'Section1'
     ) AS s
     CROSS JOIN
     (
       SELECT Faculty.FacultyID 
       FROM dbo.Faculty 
       WHERE Faculty.FirstName = @FacultyName 
       OR Faculty.LastName = @FacultyName
     ) AS f
   ;
   ```

Those variations are using your subselects without any change.  You could also rewrite the query and cross-join the tables first before filtering both in the same `WHERE`:

```
INSERT INTO
  dbo.ClassList (StudentID, FacultyID, ModifiedDate)
SELECT
  s.StudentID
, f.FacultyID
, GETDATE()
FROM
  dbo.Student AS s
, dbo.Faculty AS f
-- or: CROSS JOIN dbo.Faculty AS f
WHERE
  s.Section = 'Section1'
  AND (f.FirstName = @FacultyName 
    OR f.LastName = @FacultyName)
;
```

Note that you need to put the `OR`-ed Faculty filters in brackets in order to combine them with the Student filter properly.  Without the brackets the result would not match the desired logic due to precedence rules for the logic operators in Transact-SQL: `AND` would be evaluated first, `OR` second, while you would want it to be the other way round, hence the brackets.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't appear to have any common information in these two tables, I'd recommend doing a `distinct` `cross apply`:

```
INSERT INTO ClassList (StudentID, FacultyID, ModifiedDate)
SELECT DISTINCT student.studentID
    ,faculty.FacultyID
    ,getdate()
FROM Student
CROSS APPLY faculty
```

Comment: What does cross apply do? Yes, I am using SQL Server. My problem is the select statement I've made for the Students has a lot of results and can't be lessen by using distinction because it gives unique results. I want to add all of these results example 5 results to be added in the class list in one insert statement with the faculty.

Comment: Cross Apply is a valid answer, but you neglected to preserve OP's logic about *which* students and faculty to include.  I would suggest expanding on your answer at least that much.